# What are some coarse-grained parallel application to use as benchmarks for (Open)MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, benchmarking, openmpi

I need a coarse-grained mpi parallel application, preferably something easy to compile, configure and use, to measure the effects of VM migration in a virtual compute cluster.

Comment: why was it downvoted?

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".

Comment: When you have a requirement to test some specific aspect of (parallel) program behaviour it is almost always best to write a program which tests exactly what you want to test.  Someone else's program, designed for some other purpose, will provide data on too many confounding factors.